# Apple LLVM 6.0 error - After pulling a project changes from bitbucket

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I was just trying to run an app i'm working on with someone else and we worked on it on his computer and everything was fine, he committed the project with bitbucket, I pulled it, and when I opened it I saw this error:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The file `ASIAuthenticationDialogue.m` is not found, that's what the error message in the screenshot says. This file is part of the library [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest).

Looks like your friend used the library but didn't push it to bitbucket. I would recommend you two using Cocoapods for dependency management in your project. It'll help prevent those issues in the future.

**Update:** This is the link to the [Podspec](https://github.com/tcurdt/cocoapods-specs/blob/master/ASIHTTPRequest/1.8.1/ASIHTTPRequest.podspec) of the library.